# change the value inside the address using a patern?

Tags: c++

I am a modder and I need to change the value of the object position. I inject into the game using my dll file. I have a pattern like this 9F4FF 0 C4 A8 70 39 41 and an address like this 0x7FF6CC7DCCD. I found this address & pattern using cheat engine and x64 Debug. I need to change the value at this address using this address or pattern, how can I do this in C++?
P.S. object = entity

Comment: you cannot change the adress of an object

Comment: It's unlikely that this `object` will be located in the same position in memory from one run to another.

Comment: it is static, every session only one position, like x= 100, y= -100, z = 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use function defined in window header ...

they are :

```
ReadProcessMemory ()
WriteProcessMemory ()
```

```
BOOL WriteProcessMemory( 
  HANDLE  hProcess,
  (LPVOID  lpBaseAddress)0x7FF6CC7DCCD,
  (LPCVOID lpBuffer)yourDataBuffer,
  (SIZE_T  nSize)Sizeof(yourDataBuffer),
  (SIZE_T  *lpNumberOfBytesWritten)outWritten
);
```